# Racket Data Processing Issue: Vector Pointer is Void

Tags: vector, functional-programming, racket, tail-recursion

## Issue

I have an assignment to write a racket function that:

> takes an origin, a destination (both as 3-character airport codes),
>   and the list of flight data and returns a list of lateness statistics
>   for all flights from the origin to the destination, with a the cons
>   cell (origin . destination) as the first element.

The data has to be formatted as six proportions, proportions of flights that are at least 1, 15, 30, 60, 120, and 180 minutes late.

In my code below, I wrote a tail-first recursive function that increments a value in a vector of length six every time a matching piece of flight data is found. It then, once the list of data has been recursively checked, a list of proportions is returned.

I'm getting the following error, indicating that `part` is void when the increment code is reached. Shouldn't `part` point to the generated vector throughout the function?

## Error

```
vector-ref: contract violation
  expected: vector?
  given: #<void>
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:    3
```

## Code

```
(require "ontime.rkt")

(define (ontime-stats-by-route orig dest data)
  (define (aux orig dest data part)
    (if (null? data)
        (let ([sum (foldl + 0 (vector->list part))])
          (list (cons orig dest)
                (/ (vector-ref part 0) sum)
                (/ (vector-ref part 1) sum)
                (/ (vector-ref part 2) sum)
                (/ (vector-ref part 3) sum)
                (/ (vector-ref part 4) sum)
                (/ (vector-ref part 5) sum)))
        (if (and
             (eq? orig (car (car (cdr (car data)))))
             (eq? dest (car (cdr (car (cdr (car data)))))))
            (let ([late (car (cdr (cdr (cdr (car data)))))])
              (cond
                [(>= late 180) (aux orig dest (cdr data)
                                    (vector-set! part 5 (vector-ref part 5)))]
                [(>= late 120) (aux orig dest (cdr data)
                                    (vector-set! part 4 (vector-ref part 4)))]
                [(>= late 60) (aux orig dest (cdr data)
                                   (vector-set! part 3 (vector-ref part 3)))]
                [(>= late 30) (aux orig dest (cdr data)
                                   (vector-set! part 2 (vector-ref part 2)))]
                [(>= late 15) (aux orig dest (cdr data)
                                   (vector-set! part 1 (vector-ref part 1)))]
                [(>= late 1) (aux orig dest (cdr data)
                                  (vector-set! part 0 (vector-ref part 0)))]
                [else (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]))
            (aux orig dest (cdr data) part))))
  (let ([count (make-vector 6 0)])
    (aux orig dest data count)))

(ontime-stats-by-route "BWI" "BDL" ontime)
```

Comment: In racket `#<void>` is not a null pointer, and it's not normally used in any way for nullable values. It normally comes from procedures that don't return any useful value, usually because they have side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that mutator functions like `vector-set!`, `set-box!`, etc. return `#<void>` because they're used for their mutation, not their return values. This is good because it encourages some separation between clearly functional code (which you can manipulate and reorder however you want) and clearly imperative code (which you have to be more careful with). This is also why these functions normally end with `!`.

So instead of passing `(vector-set! part ....)` in as the new `part` argument, you should do this mutation separately, and then pass `part` itself as the argument instead since it's now mutated:

```
          (cond
            [(>= late 180)
             (vector-set! part 5 (vector-ref part 5))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [(>= late 120)
             (vector-set! part 4 (vector-ref part 4))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [(>= late 60)
             (vector-set! part 3 (vector-ref part 3))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [(>= late 30)
             (vector-set! part 2 (vector-ref part 2))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [(>= late 15)
             (vector-set! part 1 (vector-ref part 1))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [(>= late 1)
             (vector-set! part 0 (vector-ref part 0))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [else
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)])
```

Although, things like `(vector-set! part 5 (vector-ref part 5))` aren't going to change the value at index `5` at all. Did you mean `(vector-set! part 5 (add1 (vector-ref part 5)))`, given that you said you wanted to increment the values?

```
          (cond
            [(>= late 180)
             (vector-set! part 5 (add1 (vector-ref part 5)))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [(>= late 120)
             (vector-set! part 4 (add1 (vector-ref part 4)))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [(>= late 60)
             (vector-set! part 3 (add1 (vector-ref part 3)))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [(>= late 30)
             (vector-set! part 2 (add1 (vector-ref part 2)))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [(>= late 15)
             (vector-set! part 1 (add1 (vector-ref part 1)))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [(>= late 1)
             (vector-set! part 0 (add1 (vector-ref part 0)))
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)]
            [else
             (aux orig dest (cdr data) part)])
```